# Can I write all my game logic in the SpriteKit update(_:) function if I've modelled all the game logic using plain Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, sprite-kit, game-development

I've modelled a very simple 2D game in Swift. I've used structs to represent all my gameplay elements, including sprites, contacts, behaviours/movements, animations, etc. All of it is quite efficient as well as the game is very simple (eg. checking distanceSquared to determine contacts, using simple trigonometry to move only a few CGPoints for animations).

I could write my entire game logic within the `update(_:)` function in SpriteKit, however, I've read on HackingWithSwift that I should avoid writing too much code in the `update(_:)` function. Would writing all my game logic there be unwise? Or would it be better to spread out the logic between the other frame cycle event callbacks?

I only require SpriteKit's ability to draw shapes / textures at certain locations on screen + gesture recognition. Everything else is handled by my own structs. Given these are my only requirements would I be better off learning a new framework? **I'm doing this completely for fun and have all the time in the world**. In fact, I love learning new things, so I welcome a challenge as well. My #1 priority is making the game as efficient as I can, which I think should be possible using SpriteKits `update(_:)` function.

Comment: Avoid premature optimisation. You're probably better off just writing your code and then seeing if you hit any performance issues. The 'restriction' on `update()` is that the game loop wants to run every 1/60th of a second, so it needs to complete in under 0.016666s. Moving code from `update()` to another function in the game loop won't save any time.